# Python 3.8 installed on macOS Catolina, default still Python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, terminal, macos-catalina

When I open a mac terminal in Catalina Version 10 and type `python`, version 2.7.15 of python opens. However, if I type 'python3.8' from the terminal, version 3.8 opens.

Will there be any unintended consequence if Python 2.7 is completely eradicated from memory? Even if Python 2 must remain for some reason, how can I update my terminal so that the most current version of Python opens when the 'python' command is executed therein?

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf

That should help you out.
Same issue on setting default python version on a Mac.

Comment: Thank you Peter. The solution within the link you suggested was perfectly tailored for my problem but in my particular case it did not work. It was necessary for me to change ownership of files in order to complete each step but still, Python 2 comes up.